# Seting up a git server on a laptop within home network

Tags: git, home-server, repository

I have an old laptop that have no use for it. I was thinking about turning it into a git server to push my code from my desktop to it. My Desktop and Laptop are on the same network at home, so I was wondering how I can set up the server on the laptop and then push the codes from my desktop to it ? I appreciate any suggestion or article links that demonstrate the process of setting up such thing.

Comment: Have you gone through Git's [Book](http://git-scm.com/book), specifically [Chapter 4: Git on the Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server)?

Comment: Yes. I think the option I need is git over SSH protocol, but can I use that internally so that the git server isn't exposed to internet ?

Comment: Unless you port forward from your router to your local git server, it won't be visible to the public interwebs.  If you are uncertain whether or not this is already done and you set up your router, it isn't enabled by default (to protect your LAN).

Comment: so what you suggest is to use port forwarding in order to make it invisible to internet and only allow local access ?

Comment: No.  You would use port forwarding to expose it to the internet, so **if you do not want it exposed - you don't need to do anything.**  Routers default to protecting a LAN.

Comment: got it. Thanks. P.S: So all I have to do is to figure out my git server ip address and then ssh to that from my development desktop using git ? Can I also do push and pull using ssh git ?